# Remove items from xml with specific date through linq to xml in C#

Tags: .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml file that looks like this..

```
<RecentInformation>
  <User Id="99">
    <Customers>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerId>7</CustomerId>
        <Date>1/20/2010</Date>
      </Customer>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerId>67</CustomerId>
        <Date>1/20/2010</Date>
      </Customer>
    </Customers>
    <Suppliers>
      <Supplier>
        <SupplierId>11619</SupplierId>
        <Date>1/20/2010</Date>
      </Supplier>
      <Supplier>
        <SupplierId>16274</SupplierId>
        <Date>1/20/2011</Date>
      </Supplier>
    </Suppliers>
    <Enquiries>
      <Enquiry>
        <EnquiryId>136202</EnquiryId>
        <Date>1/20/2010</Date>
      </Enquiry>
      <Enquiry>
        <EnquiryId>134507</EnquiryId>
        <Date>1/20/2011</Date>
      </Enquiry>
    </Enquiries>
    <Quotes>
      <Quote>
        <QuoteId>34008</QuoteId>
        <Date>1/20/2010</Date>
      </Quote>
      <Quote>
        <QuoteId>37356</QuoteId>
        <Date>1/20/2011</Date>
      </Quote>
    </Quotes>
    <Bookings>
      <Booking>
        <BookingId>3070</BookingId>
        <Date>1/20/2011</Date>
      </Booking>
      <Booking>
        <BookingId>3251</BookingId>
        <Date>1/20/2011</Date>
      </Booking>
    </Bookings>
  </User>
</RecentInformation>
```

I want to remove all the nodes that should be less then say 15 days old.

I am using this code but it is not working for me..

```
xdoc.Descendants("User").Descendants().Descendants().Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Element("Date").Value) < date)
                            .Remove();
```

any idea??

Comment: Describe "not working" ?

Comment: exception thrown object reference not.....

Answer (score 1):

This is your line fixed

```
xdoc.Descendants("Date").Where(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Value) < date).Select(x=>x.Parent).Remove();
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply Dario. This code is working perfect for me. Thanx you so much you and all the guys who gives the answer.

Comment: perhaps Naveed Anjum is new to SO hence he dont know he have to mark it as answered. :)